# Stripe retrieve the good price ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I setup my shop with Stripe. You can buy it with the good product and with different sizes. It works well until I have to sent an email to the seller with some informations like the name of the product bought, the size of the product (product.nickname), the customer information and so on. My problem is I can't get this 'nickname'.

As I understand in Stripe, you have some Products, which can have different Prices. For me, I have a product with 3 prices. Each price has his own ID and a 'label' (according to Stripe called 'nickname' as I saw in the request). The problem came when I want to retrieve this ID to get the specific nickname (the name if the size). For some reason, the ID returned for the selected product is not the same as the ID from Stripe Dashboard. And each time I got a new purchase, this returned ID change.

In my WebhooksController in def create:

```
case event.type
when 'checkout.session.completed'
              session = event.data.object
              @order = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve({ id: session.id, expand: ["line_items", "customer"]})
    OrderMailer.order_mail(@order).deliver
end
render json: { message: 'success' }
```

In my order_mail.html.erb:

```
<% @order.line_items.data.each do |line| %>
<%= line %>
<% end %>
```

Can someone explain me why the line_item ID returned in the webhook is not the same as the Stripe dashboard ID? And how can I get and display the nickname of the price selected in my mail?

here is what I got for the `<%= line %>`

```
{ "id": "li_1K41JPFE4oPSz5YO98K2r2CW", "object": "item", "amount_subtotal": 4000, "amount_total": 4000, "currency": "eur", "description": "Soleil Levant", "price": { "id": "price_1K41JPFE4oPSz5YORWdXXGuT", "object": "price", "active": false, "billing_scheme": "per_unit", "created": 1638874459, "currency": "eur", "livemode": false, "lookup_key": null, "metadata": { }, "nickname": null, "product": "prod_KjUHP8uALE6aZI", "recurring": null, "tax_behavior": "unspecified", "tiers_mode": null, "transform_quantity": null, "type": "one_time", "unit_amount": 4000, "unit_amount_decimal": "4000" }, "quantity": 1 }
```

If I cUrl the right price:

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices/price_1JxC8kFE4oPSz5YOc391IZ9I\
  -u sk_test_51JbmGvFE4oPSz5YOsl0JTTEi0quapEwPBXQsQRbRXPdr38hSiyVDPs9LnkH4nHCGXqwoYjOTnHoH6FtIC4EP32pr00KHIxFlLp:
```

I got this:

```
{
  "id": "price_1JxC8kFE4oPSz5YOc391IZ9I",
  "object": "price",
  "active": true,
  "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
  "created": 1637247786,
  "currency": "eur",
  "livemode": false,
  "lookup_key": null,
  "metadata": {
    "nickname": "S"
  },
  "nickname": "S",
  "product": "prod_KcR0HgpfzldOj8",
  "recurring": null,
  "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
  "tiers_mode": null,
  "transform_quantity": null,
  "type": "one_time",
  "unit_amount": 4000,
  "unit_amount_decimal": "4000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work:

- First, create a Price with `nickname: "foobar"`, let’s say its ID is `"price_abc"`.
- Then, create a Checkout Session where you set `line_items[0].price: "price_abc"`.
- Later, you retrieve the Checkout Session with `expand: ["line_items"]`. If you look into `checkout.line_items.data[].price`, you will find an object that contains what you are looking for: `{ id: "price_abc", nickname: "foobar", … }`. Note that you can see the structure of the `line_items.data` object in the [Stripe documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data).

So you need to double check that you are using the correct price ID when creating the Checkout Session, and that you are looking at `checkout.line_items.data[].price` to find the `id` and `nickname` of the price.

Comment: The thing is I don't act manually on the "price_abc" because it's the choice of the customer and I can't get it through the API. The only way I can get it is when I do a Stripe::Price.retrieve('price_abc').nickname. It seems that Stripe create some instance of Prices and Product. When the payment succeed, it archives them.

Comment: You need to pass your price ID when creating the Checkout Session like this: `Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({ line_items: [ { price: "price_1JxC8kFE4oPSz5YOc391IZ9I" } ], add_other_parameters_here })`. Then you will be able to get this price and its nickname when retrieving the Checkout Session.

Comment: It doesn't change. In my OrdersController create I got `@session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        name: Stripe::Product.retrieve(@composition.product).name,
        images: [Stripe::Product.retrieve(@composition.product).images.first],
        price: @composition_id,
        amount: @composition.unit_amount,
        currency: 'eur',
        quantity: '1'
      }],
      success_url: thanks_purchase_url,
      cancel_url: fails_purchase_url
    })`

Comment: I recommend using the new Checkout (here's the [migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices#server-one-time-prices)) where you only need to pass the price ID like I showed in my previous comment.

Comment: Seems that Payment_intent from Stripe create an instance of a Product and Price then proceed the Charge, then complete the session. Finally it turn this session into an archived one. I don't know why they can't just put every information in the request. It should be easier for everyone. Furthermore it's more logical to have such information like the size of the product you want to buy...

Comment: Waow. Thank you @soma for this tip! Works well. I just changed the whole line_items [{ }] in the create and everything is fine. Dunno why previous try didn't work but thankfully it works. I added the 'quantity: 1' too. Thanks a lot!